# REST: HTTP headers or request parameters

Tags: http, rest, http-headers, httprequest

I've been putting in some research around REST. I noticed that the [Amazon S3](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/2006-03-01/API/) API uses mainly http headers for their REST interface. This was a surprise to me, since I assumed that the interface would work mainly off request parameters.

My question is this: Should I develop my REST interface using mainly http headers, or should I be using request parameters?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

The question mainly is **whether the parameters defined are part of the resource identifier (URI) or not.** if so, then you would use the request parameters otherwise HTTP custom headers. For example, passing the id of the `album` in a music gallery must be part of the URI.

Remember, for example `/employee/id/45` (Or `/employee?id=45`, REST does not have a prejudice *against* query string parameters or *for* clean slash separated URIs) identifies one resource. Now you could use content-negotiation by sending request header `content-type: text/plain` or `content-type: image/jpg` to get the info or the image. In this respect, resource is deemed to be the same and header only used to define format of the resource.

Generally, I am not a big fan of HTTP custom headers. **This usually assumes the client to have a prior knowledge of the server implementation (not discoverable through natural HTTP means, i.e. hypermedia) which always is considered a REST anti-pattern**

HTTP headers usually define aspects of HTTP **orthogonal** to what is to be achieved in the process of request/response. `Authorization` header (really a misnomer, should have been authentication) is a classic example.

Comment: This is a thoughtful and well-written response.