# Multi-page document as images over REST

Tags: rest

I'm attempting to expose a RESTful URL that returns a multi page document.  With a PDF it's quite simple in my opinion.

```
GET /documents/12345.pdf
```

But I also wish to expose the same document with an image format where each page is a separate jpg.  How would I best go about constructing the URL?

So far I'm torn between

```
GET /documents/12345/page1.jpg
```

or

```
GET /documents/12345.jpg?page=1
```

or

```
GET /document/12345?page=1&type=jpg
```

I know there is no absolute right way to do this I'm just looking for what is most intuitive.  I've spent so much time looking at this that I can't tell which one I like best or even if there is an alternate approach that would be better.

Thanks!

Comment: How about GET /documents/pdf/12345 and GET /documents/jpg/12345/1 ?

Comment: @tranceporter Post this as an answer and I'll upvote it :) And don't forget to mention the HTTP `Accept` header :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The Resource**

Your resource is the document. The PDF and JPEG are two *representations* of this resource. So both are available under

```
/documents/12345
```

**Content Negotiation**

How does the client select the PDF or the JPEG? That's what the [HTTP header `Accept`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) is for.

```
GET /documents/12345
Accept: image/jpeg
```

for the JPEG represenation,

```
GET /documents/12345
Accept: application/pdf
```

for the PDF represenation.

**Pages**

Now we still have the problem of pages. Here I would recommend to follow the approach mentioned in the comments:

```
GET /documents/12345/1
Accept: image/jpeg
```

for page 1 of the JPEG represenation.

**Problems**

There still is a small problem: What happens with this request?

```
GET /documens/12345/1
Accept: application/pdf
```

Is there 'page 1' of the PDF representation as a separate entity? Perhaps there is, if your RESTful service can generate it.

But we are not finished. What happens with this request?

```
GET /documents/12345
Accept: image/jpeg
```

Is there a single-page version of the JPEG representation? Again, perhaps there is, if your RESTful service can generate it. Perhaps it could generate a all-pages-on-one-page JPEG. If it can't, return `404 Not Found`.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the problems of specifying a pdf page or not specifying a jpg page, I'll be returning a 404 in those scenarios.

Comment: @user647772 very nice explanation. We have similar scenario but with some additional requirement. I have posted a new question for it - [Multi-page document as images over REST (additional questions)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28107711/multi-page-document-as-images-over-rest-additional-questions). I am curious, what you can suggest for our case.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
GET /documents/pdf/12345
```

and

`GET /documents/jpg/12345/1`

When using **REST**, I prefer to expose resources without using parameters or querystring. That way it fits the RESTful syntax, and is easier to parse with the in-built Routing in ASP.NET MVC.

Like @Tichodroma said about Http Headers, it is generally not preferable to use custom HTTP headers when using REST. Have a look here for good explanation:

[REST: HTTP headers or request parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7944834/rest-http-headers-or-request-parameters)

Comment: I like my answer more. But I've promised the +1 :)

Comment: lol, I am sure your's will be the accepted one. That is what I would do at least!